# How to add two fields in mongoDB using java driver

Tags: mongodb-java

```
db.student.aggregate([{$project:{rollno:1,per:{$divide:[{$add:["marks1","$marks2","$marks3"]},3]}}}])
```

how to write this query in java????? here,student is collection with fields rollno,name and marks and i have to find the percentage of the students according to their roll numbers . I am not able to write code for adding their marks as add operator does not support multiple value's for addition.

Comment: What have you tried? You'll get a better response if you post code that you've tried that doesn't work asking where to fix rather than just asking for a solution to be handed to you

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.   There are other builder pattern/conveniences but this exposes all the workings.  And leaves room for rich dynamic construction.

```
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("student");

        List<DBObject> pipe = new ArrayList<DBObject>();

        /**                                                                          
         *  Clearly, lots of room for dynamic behavior here.                         
         *  Different sets of marks, etc.  And the divisor is                        
         *  the length of these, etc.                                                
         */
        String[] marks = new String[]{"$marks1","$marks2","$marks3"};
        DBObject add = new BasicDBObject("$add", marks);
        List l2 = new ArrayList();
        l2.add(add);
        l2.add(marks.length); // 3                                                   
        DBObject divide = new BasicDBObject("$divide", l2);

        DBObject prjflds = new BasicDBObject();
        prjflds.put("rollno", 1);
        prjflds.put("per", divide);

        DBObject project = new BasicDBObject();
        project.put("$project", prjflds);
        pipe.add(project);

        AggregationOutput agg = coll.aggregate(pipe);

        for (DBObject result : agg.results()) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
```